# Joining tables without losing any information

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm currently working with two tables. Each have an ID field and a data field but both of the lists of IDs are not the same but there is some overlap (this is fine).

```
TABLE 1
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |        Data1     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         34       |
|          2          |         40       |
|          3          |         60       |

TABLE 2
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |        Data2     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         100      |
|          2          |         101      |
|          7          |         102      |
```

What I would like is one single table with 3 columns like so:

```
TABLE 3
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |        Data1     |        Data2     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         34       |       null       |
|          2          |         40       |        40        |
|          3          |         60       |        100       |
|          7          |         null     |        102       |
```

I've played about with numerous joins but can't seem to get quite the result I'm looking for and am really open to advice on this one.
I'm using oracle sql on sql developer.

Comment: Try a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `full outer join` with `coalesce` as follows:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id), t1.data1, t2.data2 
from table1 t1 full outer join table2 t2
on (t1.id = t2.id)
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I tried this and the joined table now has less rows than Table1, in my mind this should only add more rows to the table, is my intuition wrong here?

Comment: You are right. It must have same or more number of records.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the `full join`.  But Oracle also supports the `using` clause which is quite handy in this situation:

```
select id, t1.data1, t2.data2 
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     using (id);
```